# How can I set Minimum & Maximum items quantity per order based on categories Wooccomerce using PHP

Tags: php, woocommerce, code-snippets

I have this issue: I have 4 categories, but I want that users can purchase min & a max of 3 items in a total of 3 of these categories. And, for the other category, they can only add 1 item per order (disallowing the option to add items from other categories)

Example:

Category #1, #2, and #3: min/max 3 items per order, can't add items from category #4.

Category #4: 1 item per order, can't add items from categories #1, #2 & #3.

Thank you!

I have tried many plugins and snippets but none of them worked as I need it. I would rather add some coding instead a plugin to make this work.

Code I tried and it didn't work:

```
// Validate minimum and maximum items per order based on categories
function custom_validate_cart_items($passed) {
    // Set your category IDs
    $category_ids = array(1, 2, 3);
    $category_id_single = 4;

    // Initialize counters and flags
    $category_count = 0;
    $category_single_count = 0;
    $has_category_ids = false;
    $has_category_single = false;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $product_cat_ids = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'ids'));

        if (in_array($product_id, $category_ids)) {
            $category_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
            $has_category_ids = true;
        } elseif ($product_cat_ids && $product_cat_ids[0] == $category_id_single) {
            $category_single_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
            $has_category_single = true;
        }
    }

    // Check if the quantities exceed the limits
    if ($category_count < 3 && $has_category_single) {
        wc_add_notice(__('You must select a minimum of 3 items from categories 1, 2, or 3.'), 'error');
        $passed = false;
    }

    if ($category_single_count > 1 && ($category_count === 0 || $has_category_ids)) {
        wc_add_notice(__('You can only select 1 item from category 4.'), 'error');
        $passed = false;
    }

    // Check if items from Category 4 are being added when there are items from Categories 1, 2, or 3, and vice versa
    if ($has_category_ids && $has_category_single) {
        wc_add_notice(__('You cannot select items from category 4 if you have items from categories 1, 2, or 3, and vice versa.'), 'error');
        $passed = false;
    }

    return $passed;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'custom_validate_cart_items', 10, 1);`
```

Comment: I think you should try to code something from scratch, and when/if  you're stuck ask here.  You cannot ask for a full working solution without some effort... Maybe the downvote refers to this

Comment: Just updated the question with the code I tried and it didn't work

Comment: Ok, now we can see. Never say on Stack Overflow "*didn't work*", you must specify the error, or the odd behavior of your program. Can you elaborate? Thank you.

Comment: Also, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)